# Invariant Violation: Could not find “store” in the context of “Connect(Login)”

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, provider

I recently started learning react-native and redux. To try redux for the first time, I used an online tutorial to implement redux in a basic login screen I had already created using react-native.

I used an example state with value 0 which didn't really do anything. I wanted to mess around with it by changing its value later. I was able to follow the tutorial well without any errors until I changed my *export default Login* to *Export default connect(myStateToProps)(Login)*, and I got the following error-

[Invariant Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zImV.jpg)

Here is the login screen code:

```
import {Button, StyleSheet, View, Text, TextInput, Alert} from 'react-native';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider, connect} from 'react-redux';

const iniState = {
  example: 0
}

const reducer = (state = iniState) => {
  return state
}

const store = createStore(reducer)


export class Login extends Component {
  state = {username: '', password: ''};

  checkLogin() {
    const {username, password} = this.state;
    if (username == 'naman' && password == 'naman') {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('calculator');
    } else {
      Alert.alert('Login Failed', 'Incorrect Username or Password', [
        {
          text: 'Okay',
        },
      ]);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.heading}>Naman's Calculator</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          underlineColorAndroid="black"
          placeholder="Username"
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({username: text})}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          underlineColorAndroid="black"
          placeholder="Password"
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({password: text})}
        />
        <Button title={'Login'} onPress={_ => this.checkLogin()} />
      </View>
    </Provider>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    example: state.example
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Login);


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  heading: {
    fontSize: 25,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  input: {
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20,
    padding: 20,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#72DC8C'
  },
});
```

This Login screen is then exported into the App.js as follows:

```
import {Platform, StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Calculator from './Calculator';
import Login from './Login';

const AppNavigation = createStackNavigator({
  login: Login,
  calculator: Calculator,
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigation);
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work because you're using the `<Provider />` component on the same component as `connect()`. What's happening is: `connect` is wrapping your component with a redux wrapper and the `<Provider />` is inside the redux wrapper. But the `<Provider />` always needs to be above any redux wrapper components.

You need to create a new component like `<App />`, put your store in there and then include the login below the `<App />`.

Comment: It worked! I created another js file, put everything I wanted to wrap under it and then added it in the render for my login as a new component like you mentioned. After putting the provider around it, it worked as intended. Thank you so much :)